# Where does VVVVVV save game progress?

Tags: vvvvvv

In what location on the filesystem does VVVVVV store your progress through the game when you save in game?

Comment: The save game is in a folder covered in spikes with two tiny, fast-moving folders that you must click on in rapid succession.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In whatever folder Flash stores its saved data. On Windows, that's `%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\<random characters>\localhost\path\to\vvvvvv\vvvvvv.exe\`.The random characters vary from computer to computer, so you'll have to check for yourself.

(I don't know where Flash stores data on Linux or Mac, but I would expect it's somewhere in your user folder.)

To give a concrete example, if you've placed VVVVVV.exe in `C:\Program Files\VVVVVV\`, then your saved data will be in `%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\<random characters>\localhost\program files\vvvvvv\vvvvvv.exe\`.

If you've bought it on Steam, you should go to `%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\<random characters>\localhost\path\to\steam\steamapps\common\vvvvvv\vvvvvv.exe`.

Note that this mean you *will* lose your saves if you do a generic clean of your Flash saved data.

Comment: If you have version 2 of the game (released July 2011 in the humble bundle) this doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 12):

As for version 2.0 (rewritten in C++), the save lies in:

> %userprofile%\Documents\VVVVVV\Saves

This is where the Desura version puts the save. And Steam. 
I believe the HIB version puts it at the same location.

Answer (score 10):

That depends on your installed version of VVVVV.

**Version 1.0 STEAM:**
*Windows:* %APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects\<random letters>\localhost\<path to steam>\steamapps\common\vvvvvv\vvvvvv.exe
*Mac:* ~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/<random letters>/localhost/<path to steam data>/steamapps/common/vvvvvv/vvvvvv

**Version 2.0:**
*Windows:* %USERPROFILE%\Documents\VVVVVV\Saves
*Mac:* /Users/<username>/Documents/VVVVVV/Saves

([Source & Unofficial Save Converter](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2024327))

Comment: The Linux directory for version 2.0 is `~/.vvvvvv/` (if you wish to add it to your answer)

Comment: Linux directory for latest version is `~/.local/share/VVVVVV/saves`

Answer (score -1):

The VVVVVV readme.txt says:

> VVVVVV is a flash projector, so it saves your game in your system's flash
>   cache. Warning: if you clear your flash cache with a tool like CCleaner, it may 
>   delete your saved games!

So it seems like the game state is saved as a flash cookie.